# Make side nav height match angular ui-view div height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Added some jquery to make one div that is in my index (master page) the full height as any content in any view. Basically, match div height of one to div height of another. My jquery code is:

```
var divHeight = $('.rightSide').height(); 
$('.tabNav').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');
```

This is applying to this html:

```
<div class="col-md-2 tabNav">
    <ul class="tabTitle">
        <p>Project tools</p>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#/home">Welcome</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Experiments</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Interview Notes</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="tabTitle">
        <p>Hypothesis worksheets</p>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="/#/steps">Problem phase</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="/#/solutionHyp">Solution phase</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Service phase</a></li>
        <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Growth phase</a></li>                
    </ul>            
</div>
<div ui-view class="rightSide">
</div>
```

Notice that the div with angular directive ui-view has the class of "rightSide"? Why does this not give me the results I am after?

Comment: first thing to check is what are you actually setting. add console.log(divHeight) right after the line where you set it.

Comment: Do you actually get the min-height on that element?

Comment: @Flink - not sure I understand your question. It should grab it from the DOM tree.

Comment: @VladimirM - even though JQuery is loaded, it does show a ReferenceError for $ in the console. Why would this happen? I can see JQuery loaded in the sources.

Comment: Inspect the `.rightSide` Element. Does the element actually get a `min-height`? Also try to add your jQuery at the end of your `body` element.

Comment: @Flink - my jquery is at the end. It didn't get min-height, but it does get a height and still does not apply that.

Comment: Also your own script should be referenced after jquery

Answer (score 0):

you javascript is OK, you're actually missing content in the .rightside div.

once you put should be ok. check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqx6jp7q/1/

```
var divHeight = $('.rightSide').height(); 
$('.tabNav').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');
```

Comment: That is not correct. It will not work with the directive in place. That div gets populated when the view is rendered to the DOM.